# Can Sql Server Return a Result Set to a Calling Application from a Stored Procedure with an Output Cursor?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, cursors

I'm new to a team where we are converting a transactional Oracle DB to SQL Server. There are a lot of DB objects so an automated tool was used for the initial conversion and we must fix the remaining issues for our application.

One issue is that Oracle returns a cursor to the calling app from a stored procedure. We don't want to change the code, so the app must support the same functionality with SQL Server. Is this possible? I know SQL Server supports returning an output cursor from a stored procedure within another stored procedure. I don't know whether that cursor can be returned to a calling application and haven't found any examples so far.

Comment: No, SQL Server doesn't have output cursors - in SQL Server, to return a result set from a stored procedure, you just have a `SELECT  .....` statement at the end of your stored procedure that fetches the rows to return

Comment: What about this? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175498%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A result set is returned from SQL Server through the dbconnection object. I've never compared the differences between the Oracle cursor and the SQL Server result set, but they are essentially the same, a set of data. I have used both in the past, but have no details for you.

I'm sure it makes a difference what front-end you are using, but you are on the right track.

Comment: Thanks. The app uses standard ADO.NET. I will try the Select and post an update.